# Website unaccessible - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: website

I used to access a website in my Edge browser. This website is no longer accessible on the machine in question. I can access this website on another machine using the same network, internet connection and VPN. I did not block this website in the Microsoft hosts file. What is going on?

Comment: Have you restarted your router?

Comment: Yes I have @DavidPostill